# "fiscal revenue" VS "fiscal revenues"

Tags: singular-vs-plural

> 1. Now, productivity growth without job creation and more fiscal **revenue** is unprecedented in economic history.
> 2. Now, productivity growth without job creation and more fiscal **revenues** is unprecedented in economic history.

The choice between revenue and revenues havs vexed me greatly. I saw it change from time to time. Is there a rule here?

Answer (score 2):

If you simply mean an increase in the amount of money received, I would say **more fiscal revenue**. If you mean additional sources of revenue, I would say **more fiscal revenues**, where "revenues" is understood to mean something like "revenue streams".

See some of the lower definitions [here](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/revenue).

Comment: so revenue can be used as a countable word or noncountable word?

Comment: @MikePhilip Yes. See some of the alternate definitions in the link.

Answer (score 0):

See, let's take a look [at this page.](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/the-plural-of/revenue.html)

Says,

> The noun revenue can be countable or uncountable.
>
> In more general, commonly used, contexts, the plural form will also be revenue.

So the noun revenue is either countable or non countable.

And interestingly, it says,

> However, in more specific contexts, the plural form can also be revenues e.g. in reference to **various types** of revenues or **a collection** of revenues.

So in case company A produces items A and B and C and each revenue is recognized individually and respectively, it would mean, like, Revenues. A 100 millions, B 150 millions, C  200 millions, would be reported in financial statements? I guess the quote would be saying so.

Thank you.